# A following up question on Weierstrass function approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, weierstrass-approximation

This is a following-up question of

[Proof — Weierstrass Approximation Theory for derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180883/proof-weierstrass-approximation-theory-for-derivatives)

and $f \in C^{\infty}$

Basically I wanted to explore whether there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that $p^{(k)}_n$ converges
uniformly on $[0, 1]$ to $f^{(k)}$ (the k-th derivative)
for $ k = 0, 1, 2, . . . $

My idea is as follows:

Given any $k$, there exists  a sequence of polynomial $q$ such that as $n\gt N$ we have $\|f^{(k)} - q_n\| \lt \epsilon.$ This is a direct consequence of Weierstrass Theorem.

We define $g(x) =  f^{(k)}(x)$, and let $p_n(x) = \underbrace{\int_{0}^{x}... \int_{0}^{x}}_\text{$k$ times}q_n(s)ds + f(0)$ and we are done.

Given that such $k$ is an arbitrary positive integer, the result holds for all $k$.

Is this proof valid?